# Building executable JAR in NetBeans not working

Tags: java, netbeans, executable-jar

I have seen a lot of references to this type of problem on StackOverflow and other places on the internet but the solution everybody else is happy with isn't working for me.

The issue:
I've created Java projects and would like to run them via executable .jar files. When I try to run a .jar file for my project I get a "Could not find the main class: classname. Project will exit." error.

Solutions I've read about:
-editing the 'main class' from the project properties "run" tab and choose the location of the main class. 

-edit the manifest file to include:
      Main-Class: classname

None of this has worked. Entering the right class in the project properties, and with an updated manifest file I still get the main class not found error and I have run out of ideas on how to fix this.

Any help would be more than slightly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a copy of my actual manifest file in its entirity:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: TestCode
<invisible blank line here>
```

I've heard that a blank line is required in the .mf file so I've put one in there just in case.

The project name is TestCode it is in the "default package" under TestCode.java

EDIT 2:

I unpacked the .jar file and looked at its contents the manifest.mf file inside the .jar has the correct class path listed for the .class file which contains the main method. (most of these projects have only one .class file) and yet I still get the "Could not find the main class" error.

The main class is clearly inside the .jar file, the manifest properly points to it and it still won't run the program.

Comment: did you put in good format? in my case it works

Comment: What "type" of project did you create?  A Netbeans "Application" is capable of providing this functionality, but I'm not sure about a Netbeans "Library" project

Comment: it is a Java Application project

Comment: isn't your TestCode class in any package?

Comment: specify fully qualified classname for Main-Class:

Comment: http://www.leigero.com/executablejar.jpg
What would the fully qualified class name be? Isn't it usually packagename.classlocation What is it when its in the 'default package'
and just to note, I've got other packages where I named the 'default package' and putting packagename.classlocation still does it

Comment: Does your NetBeans project have a main class defined? (Project Properties -> Run -> Main Class)

Comment: Yes, in my comment just above yours I included a link to a .png which shows the error, the file structure and the manifest file as well as my project properties.

Comment: You have no package for your class, this is strongly discouraged (and NetBeans should have warned you when you created the class). Try putting the class into a proper package. I'm not sure executable jars will work with classes without a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write

```
main -class: Packagename.Classname
```